# Finding a table row

Tags: ruby, rspec, html-table, row

I am working on an RSpec test whereby a designated row in a table of users will be selected. The HTML for the table of users is as follows:

```
<tr id="IvUserList_DXDataRow0" class="dxgvDataRow_Injixo">
  <td class="dxgv">J.P.</td>
  <td class="dxgv">Mc Fly</td>
  <td class="dxgv">asd@kl.co</td>
  <td class="dxgv">30.01.2012</td>
  <td class="dxgvCommandColumn_Injixo dxgv" align="center">
  ..........
  ..........
  </td>
</tr>'
```

At the end of each row there is a dropdown button "dxgvCommandColumn_Injixo dxgv" which is used to display a context menu of further options (Edit, Password, Delete). I am trying to select the button for the row testuser@test.com but it is mistakenly selecting the first occurence of the button each time.

My code is as follows:

```
 before(:each) do
   within(:xpath, '//*[@id="IvUserList_DXMainTable"]') do
     row = find(:xpath, '//*[@class="dxgvDataRow_Injixo"]')
     row.should have_selector('td', :class => 'dxgv', :textContent => 'testuser@test.com')
     within(row) do
       find(:xpath, '//*[@class="dxgvCommandColumn_Injixo dxgv"]').click
     end     
   end
   sleep 1
   click_link 'Edit User'
   sleep 1
  end
```

Can someone please tell me if there is a better way to go about solving this problem?